# How to drive Firebug from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firebug

I would like to capture the Net panel output from Firebug while running a test through WebDriver. I was thinking of doing this using NetExport to dump the info to a har file. How can I activate Firebug to do the export while a particular page is displayed using "driver.get()"?

Comment: What language are you using? java, C#, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the Firestarter extension in addition to Firebug and NetExport. Here's how I do it in Ruby:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

profile.add_extension "path/to/firebug.xpi"
profile.add_extension "path/to/fireStarter.xpi"
profile.add_extension "path/to/netExport.xpi")

profile['extensions.firebug.currentVersion']    = "1.7.0a3" # avoid 'first run' tab
profile["extensions.firebug.previousPlacement"] = 1
profile["extensions.firebug.onByDefault"]       = true
profile["extensions.firebug.defaultPanelName"]  = "net"
profile["extensions.firebug.net.enableSites"]   = true

profile["extensions.firebug.netexport.defaultLogDir"]          = output_dir
profile["extensions.firebug.netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport"] = true

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Equivalent APIs are avilable in Java. Make sure the extensions are compatible with each other (and your Firefox version).

If you're using Ruby (or just want to quickly launch a HAR viewer from the command line), check out my [HAR gem](http://github.com/jarib/har) for an easy way to work with the data later.

Comment: Thanks so much for your instructions @jarib. But I am unable to get the FirefoxDriver to add any of the extensions. I don't see the "1.7.0a3" extension anymore (all the 1.7 stuff is called 1.7X.0a? and I downnloaded 1.7X.0a3 and set the version to the same). There is no exception thrown by the addExtension method either. Has anyone got the firebug extension to load successfully using Java?

Comment: As mentioned, the XPIs must be compatible with each other and your current Firefox version - just because I used 1.7 doesn't mean it's right for you. So make sure it all works by installing them manually first. FirefoxProfile.addExtension won't throw errors if they're incompatible (it simply copies the files into the right place), and Firefox will just ignore incompatible extensions.

Comment: I have it working now. I had a typo in one of the options. I also needed to add a sleep of 3 secs after the 'driver.get()' call to get netexport to save the log. Thanks very much.

Comment: I spoke too fast. This is just not behaving in a stable manner. Sometimes the output gets written out, at other times it doesn't (mostly it doesn't). What I find is that the Net panel shows the first request as never completing for some reason e.g. if I go to 'faban.org', firebug shows 'Get faban.org' with a spinning icon in the 'Timeline' column. This happens for many different sites and when it does, I don't get a har file. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To run Firebug within Selenium WebDriver using Java:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.F12).build().perform();
```