# Java Selenium loading time took so long on findelements

Tags: java, selenium

I use selenium to remote firefox and its working fine, but lately as I observe. once my internet slow, firefox do not stop loading after moving to another page.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
```

above works when trying to connect to the baseurl. but

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("body-container")).click();
```

after this findElement move to next page and wont stop loading;

Comment: Does this apply to particular URLs? Also can you see from Firefox status bar that any requests are slow/blocking?

Comment: Another possibility is that the HTTP requests between the WebDriver client code and the remote driver are slowed, and that will affect the performance of any lookup to some extent. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol

Comment: You could diagnose the network timings using Firebug and NetExport: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4980226/954442

Comment: firefox says "Waiting for www.url.com" but the page load completely but do not stop loading. what seems the problem?

Comment: Could you check the time line in firebug, Then post it in the question? It looks like some resources are slow.